# Does reblogging the statement "You are the one, the one and the only one" make you a mushrik?

Tags: sharia, shirk

I've reblogged a photo on my blog, and in the photo was figured an actress saying these words: "*You are the one, the one and the only one*"

Did I do shirk? I posted this unknowingly and my goal was not to do shirk, then a few weeks ago I found out this on tumblr and I tried to delete my reblog but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam-O-Alaykoum

Here i don't think that you've done Shirk, because as you've described the situation above, you hadn't the intention to do Shirk by posting this picture, your intention was white, but it is clear that this Artist isn't a Muslim at least till now we didn't have any information about her commitment to Islam, these words are promoting Shirk and posting it is a mistake, plus posting a picture of a women with unveiled body or hair is also a mistake, so, i suggest to remove this post and ask Allah to forgive you.

And Allah knows better.

Answer (score 1):

Shirk only exists if you BELIEVE in another God or divinity of other objects.

So sharing something WITHOUT believing in the divinity of the picture is NOT shirk.

It would be shirk if you BELIEVED the picture was a God or divine.

But re-blogging something like that could be haraam because it's spreading the wrong message.